# One to Many Relationship with existing database. how to connect?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, one-to-many

I have a problem in creating a relationship with an existing database.

```
(Table1 one)
business_list (Table name)
Business_Number (PK)
name
description

(Table2 many)
setup_project (Table name)
project_id (PK)
ClientID (FK / Business_Number)
name
description

BusinessList (Model)
protected $table = 'general.business_list';
public function setupProject(){
    return $this->hasMany(SetupProject::class, 'ClientID', 'Business_Number');
}

SetupProject (Model)
protected $table = 'general.setup_project';
public function businessList(){
    return $this->belongsTo(BusinessList::class);
}

(Controller)
public function showProjects($id)
{
    $setupProject = BusinessList::findOrFail($id)->setupProject;
    return $this->showAll($setupProject);
}
```

Here is what i get in the postman, but i already define the local key. please help me guys. thank you
[image]

Comment: this postman error is not related to hasmany relationship

Comment: you are getting error because you are using find to search and it search from id and you have no id column

Comment: yes sir, but i already added a local_key parameter in hasMany relationship. i dont know why i get that error.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. you need to declare your primary key in the model.

```php
protected $primaryKey = 'Business_Number';
```

Comment: Beccause when you use `BusinessList::findOrFail($id)` it runs `select * from table where id =  $id` and your primary key was different from default key